# WPDB get_row like string returning null?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm having a problem comparing $url and the url in the database. For some reason this always returns null, but if I drop the url it works fine. I also copied the url directly out of the database so it's an exact match.

Any suggestions on how to query the url string for a match?

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE service = $package_id AND url LIKE $url", ARRAY_A );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `$url`, in that with the LIKE operator you have to surround the value with % signs to make it match somewhere in the string. So try this instead:

`$row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE service = $package_id AND url LIKE '%$url%'", ARRAY_A );`

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit because I forgot the single quotes around '%$url%' -- Did you try that as well?

Comment: Thanks this worked! I tried this earlier, but missed the single quotes around $url. I'll mark this as solved in 10 minutes when it's available.

Comment: Woohoo! happy to help!

Comment: If user input contributes to this query (e.g. it's a user-specified/user-modifiable "url" parameter), you should also use `$wpb->prepare` around the query string (and set args) so that the query is protected